# Why am I getting keyboard input lag on the GDM login screen?

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, gdm

I am facing a strange issue with Ubuntu 20.04. The keyboard input lags a lot on the login screen when entering password. After login there is no lag.

My device is HP Elitebook Folio 1040 G1.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment out all these files `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` and `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`

and open file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

```
WaylandEnable=false  # comment this line
WaylandEnable=true  # or uncomment this line
```

then reboot at the end.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround came from [this thread](https://qastack.com.br/ubuntu/906723/fn-media-keys-slow-delayed-on-ubuntu-gnome-17-04).

I commented one line in `/usr/share/xkb/symbols/br` so that it looks like this:

// modifier_map Mod3 {Scroll_Lock};